# mvc4 adding control id to url - eg: http://myapp/mycontroller/myview#myanchorid

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

My application has a page with many sections that requires lots of scrolling when linked to from other pages in the application.  Is there a way to pass the control id on the url from the actionlink request on the calling page?  That would allow me to scroll directly to that section easily on the target page.

There's probably something obvious that I'm missing.

---

Here's the helper I used to make it work.

```
@helper  Action(actionName As String, controllerName As String, fragment As String, routeValues As Object,     displayText As String) 
     Dim url As New UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext)
     Dim str As String = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(routeName:=Nothing, actionName:=actionName, controllerName:=controllerName, routeValues:=New System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), fragment:=fragment, protocol:=Nothing, _
hostName:=Nothing, routeCollection:=url.RouteCollection, requestContext:=url.RequestContext, includeImplicitMvcValues:=True)

     Dim outurl As String = String.Format("<a href=\'{0}\'>{1}</a>", str, displayText)

     @MvcHtmlString.Create(outurl)

End helper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In System.Web.Mvc namespace you can find class UrlHelper with method GenerateUrl(), where you can build your url with **fragment** argument which is your control-id.

Comment: all set now - added solution to answer